# ¿Cómo ocultar columna con datos en Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

tengo un problema al querer ocultar columnas de un reporte:
Segun buscando en foros, si quiero ocultar solo bastaria con suprimir el encabezado desde el "Format Object" que se abre al dar click derecho, pero al momento de compilar y generar el reporte, sigue apareciendo la columna.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No se si habra un paso mas que se deba añadir, ya que soy nuevo usando esto.
Agradezco la ayuda que pueda recibir

PD:La version de mi Crystal Reports es: 13.0.3500.0

Comment: Aparece el titulo, o el titulo dejo de aparecer y aparece el contenido?

Comment: Hola, ningún cambio simple que hago en el reporte se refleja cuando compila el proyecto, ya sea mover de lugar una casilla de texto o eliminar alguna columna, lo cual se me hace raro, no se si habrá una serie de pasos que se deban realizar, ya que soy nuevo usando esto

Comment: parece que no estas tocando el reporte que corresponde entonces...